# How to select data from dataset for the given condition using time series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

```
     Patient_id    timestamp    date          time    blood_sugar
0   pid11928    1.670000e+12    30-12-22    16:53:20    100
1   pid11928    1.600000e+12    05-10-20    12:46:40    98
2   pid11928    1.580000e+12    10-03-20    3:13:20     102
3   pid12334    1.480000e+12    07-01-17    17:26:40    99
4   pid12334    1.490000e+12    03-05-17    11:13:20    98
5   pid14556    1.500000e+12    30-06-17    8:06:40     115
6   pid14556    1.490000e+12    06-03-17    14:20:00    114
7   pid11223    1.600000e+12    11-09-20    7:40:00     100
8   pid11223    1.590000e+12    15-07-20    10:46:40    100
9   pid11223    1.580000e+12    21-03-20    17:00:00    95
```

How can i select the users whose blood sugar increased/decreased from the given time invervals?

Here 1 user has multiple readings at different time intervals so i have to select the list of users who meet the condition of increased blood sugar and also find by how much value did it increase.

I tried separating the df by unique users and then performing operations ,but it becomes too confusing for larger data sets.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - please share with us what you have tried, and also remove the image of the dataset as you have already posted the data. See [this meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check if the diff from the prior reading to the new is greater than zero for any given patient?  If so try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Patient_id': ['pid11928', 'pid11928', 'pid11928', 'pid12334', 'pid12334', 'pid14556', 'pid14556', 'pid11223', 'pid11223', 'pid11223'], 'timestamp': [1670000000000.0, 1600000000000.0, 1580000000000.0, 1480000000000.0, 1490000000000.0, 1500000000000.0, 1490000000000.0, 1600000000000.0, 1590000000000.0, 1580000000000.0], 'date': ['30-12-22', '05-10-20', '10-03-20', '07-01-17', '03-05-17', '30-06-17', '06-03-17', '11-09-20', '15-07-20', '21-03-20'], 'time': ['16:53:20', '12:46:40', '3:13:20', '17:26:40', '11:13:20', '8:06:40', '14:20:00', '7:40:00', '10:46:40', '17:00:00'], 'blood_sugar': [100, 98, 102, 99, 98, 115, 114, 100, 100, 95]})


df['diff'] = df.groupby('Patient_id')['blood_sugar'].diff()
df.loc[df['diff'].gt(0)]
```

Output

```
  Patient_id     timestamp      date     time  blood_sugar  diff
2   pid11928  1.580000e+12  10-03-20  3:13:20          102   4.0
```